# Alternative for faucet "Unfortunately the faucet has run dry message"

Tags: smart-contracts, faucet

Is there any alternative for faucet as I am seeing "Unfortunately the faucet has run dry" message on the site. I don't understand what "faucet has run dry" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using https://teztnets.xyz ?

https://faucet.tezos.com has been deprecated. Now, each test network has its own faucet.

Comment: If faucet.tezos.com is deprecated and we are following on the tutorials from Tezos where above is a requirement how should we proceed ?

Comment: What would be the alternative if we are testing using a tezos sandbox and tezos-client

Comment: I do not know which tutorial you are using. But for using the sandbox, you could look at https://wiki.tezosagora.org/build/clients/run-a-sandbox. The examples still use the Florence protocol, but should not be a problem.

Comment: The mockup mode is also available. It should give all the features you need for testing contracts. https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/mockup.html?highlight=mockup#mockup-mode

Comment: If you are using a public test network, then you need to use the faucets available at: https://teztnets.xyz

Comment: Thanks, @Rodrigo Quelhas We are trying to setup an Oracles and for the said purpose we want these faucets to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I've develop a little faucet for testnet (only Ithacanet for instance)

https://tezos-testnet-faucet.netlify.app/

Feel free to use it and give me some feedback about it ;)